# Elasticsearch Logstash - fix date and time match

Tags: java, datetime, elasticsearch, timestamp, logstash

I'm trying to parse this format of timestamp:

```
2021-09-01T13:26:01.284625+02:00
```

As it's impossible to change it for something more readable I have to deal with this kind of date and time.

I thought that something simple like this will work:

```
match => ["logdate","yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZ", "ISO8601"]
```

...but it won't.

I created this match basing on documentation -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.10/plugins-filters-date.html

Can somebody point out what's wrong with this match?

Comment: I think you're just missing single ticks around `T`: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZ`

Comment: In addition to what @Val said I’d try `XXX` for the offset (the `+02:00`).